# Where can I store my cosmetic gear?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-x

I've been obtaining a lot of cosmetic gear from various side quests -- things like swimsuits, tank tops, sunglasses, and so on. Most of my inventory is cosmetic items now, because I don't want to sell them as I have no idea if I can even get replacements later.

Is there somewhere to store these items? I like to have a clean inventory so it's easier to compare gear I find out in the field.

Comment: At the very least, you can buy Diving Gear and Swimsuits at the shop.

Comment: @Nolonar True, but I've found special _pink_ swimsuit gear!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no special place to store this gear. It'll have to occupy space in your inventory. Thankfully, you can have 999 pieces of armor so you can hold onto quite a bit, and most of it is low AC so it falls near the bottom.

Comment: It'd be great if the game had something like Wildstar's Wardrobe, where you can place a copy of an item for cosmetic purposes without taking up inventory space, but no dice.

Comment: @Tylor I totally agree. It's mostly annoying because I like to only carry around what I need in my inventory, but that's strictly not possible because I might want to use something later for cosmetics. If I go on a sell-spree, I might lose the item permanently, too. It's just a bit frustrating.